# Sitemap with laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel, sitemap

I works in my project by LARAVEL.

I want to make sitemap. This is my controller:

```
class SitemapController extends BaseController {
        public function index() {
                header("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8");
                return View::make('sitemap');
        }
}
```

And This is my view *sitemap.blade.php*:

```
{{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>}}
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
        <url>
                <loc>{{url()}}</loc>
                <priority>0.5</priority>
        </url>
        .
        .
        .
</urlset>
```

But result not appeared as XML. It appeared as a normal text.

Comment: did u solved ur issue by this method? because i just started using this controller view method.

Comment: yes, I wrote solution at answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works when I used:

```
{{'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'}}
```

and I updated my controller as:

```
class SitemapController extends BaseController {
        public function index() {
                $content = View::make('sitemap');
                return Response::make($content)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=utf-8');
        }
}
```

Comment: i did have to use {{ '<'.'?'.'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' }} to be able to get it to work. (laravel 4.2)

Comment: In laravel 5 I used {!! '<'.'?'.'xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' !!}

Comment: I just ditched blade for this line and used `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>` to get it working for me

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you should use this package https://github.com/RoumenDamianoff/laravel-sitemap

### Installation

Add the following to your `composer.json` file :

`"roumen/sitemap": "dev-master"`

Then register this service provider with Laravel :

`'Roumen\Sitemap\SitemapServiceProvider',`

Publish configuration file. (OPTIONAL)

```
php artisan config:publish roumen/sitemap
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the XML declaration in single quotes:

```
{{'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>'}}
```

Works for my in Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

Add the XML declaration like this:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' ?>
```